# Inequality involving exponential functions and logarithms

Tags: inequality

I am trying to analyze the following inequality and was hoping to get some assistance:

Given $x_1,...,x_n \in R$ and $\displaystyle r_k :=\sum_{i=1}^n I(x_i\ge x_k)$, for some $\tau>0$, I am wondering whether the following inequality holds:

$$\frac{\exp(\tau x_k)}{\sum_{i=1}^n \exp(\tau x_i)} \le \log\left(1+\frac{1}{r_k}\right)$$

Does this inequality hold under these conditions? I have plotted several graphs and it even appears that the value of $\tau$ can be arbitrary.
However, I would like to confirm this and understand the proof.

Moreover, is there for some $C > 0 $ such that:
$$ \log\left(1+\frac{1}{r_k}\right) \le C\frac{\exp(\tau x_k)}{\sum_{i=1}^n \exp(\tau x_i)} $$

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!